# HI Everyone , i want to move header section in menu bar ? i dont know how ? can anybody help me out for this question

Tags: magento-1.9, header, ce-1.9.2.4, topmenu, custom-menu

[image]

I want to **move header** section into **menu bar**. Can anyone help me out for this?

Comment: Magento version ?

Comment: Magento 1.9.2.4